# Parameterize the Loop in selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to write for loop 
for this id is repeating

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl03_TxtDescrp")).sendKeys("eldpone@23");
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl04_selectchk")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl04_TxtDescrp")).sendKeys("eldpone@23");
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl05_selectchk")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl05_TxtDescrp")).sendKeys("eldpone@23");
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl06_selectchk")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl06_TxtDescrp")).sendKeys("eldpone@23");
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl07_selectchk")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl07_TxtDescrp")).sendKeys("eldpone@23");
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl08_selectchk")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl08_TxtDescrp")).sendKeys("eldpone@23");
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl09_selectchk")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl09_TxtDescrp")).sendKeys("eldpone@23");
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl10_selectchk")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl10_TxtDescrp")).sendKeys("eldpone@23");
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl11_selectchk")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl11_TxtDescrp")).sendKeys("eldpone@23")
```

Comment: What language are you using Selenium Webdriver in?

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming the loop is from 3 to 11 and you first click on each element and send text after that**, below code will work for you:

```
    WebElement eleSend = null;
    WebElement eleClick = null;
    String Locator_StartUpto9 = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl0";
    String Locator_StartAfter9 = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl";
    String Locator_SendKeys_End = "_TxtDescrp";
    String Locator_Click_End = "_selectchk";
    String Locator_SendKeys = null;
    String Locator_Click = null;

    for(int i = 3; i <= 11; i++){
        if(i<=9){
            Locator_SendKeys = Locator_StartUpto9 + i + Locator_SendKeys_End;
            Locator_Click = Locator_StartUpto9 + i + Locator_Click_End;
        }else{
            Locator_SendKeys = Locator_StartAfter9 + i + Locator_SendKeys_End;
            Locator_Click = Locator_StartAfter9 + i + Locator_Click_End;
        }

        eleSend = driver.findElement(By.id(Locator_SendKeys));
        eleClick = driver.findElement(By.id(Locator_Click));

        eleClick.click();
        eleSend.sendKeys("eldpone@23");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have to click from 3 to 11:
try with:

```
WebElement web = null;
for(int i = 3; i <= 11; i++){
    web = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl0"+i+"_TxtDescrp");
    web.click();
    web.sendKeys("eldpone@23");
}
```

But it would be better if you provide your html, so that we could provide more optimised code.
And if you are having all under same tags you can create a xpath as

```
//<tag>[contains(@id,'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard')]
```

and get all webElements using findElements method and then use

```
foreach(WebElement web : list){
    web.click();
    web.sendKeys("eldpone@23");
}
```

**Correction:**
based on the correction provided by Shoaib, I would prefer:

```
List<WebElement> lstEle = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id[contains(.,'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard')]]"));
foreach(WebElement webEle : lstEle){
    if(webEle.getAttribute("id").contains("selectchk"))
        webEle.click;
    else
        webEle.sendKeys("eldpone@23");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correction to vivek's code

```
WebElement web = null;
for(int i = 3; i <= 11; i++)
{
    webTextBox = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl0"+i+"_TxtDescrp");
    webTextBox .sendKeys("eldpone@23");

    webCheckBox = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl0"+i+"_selectchk");
    webCheckBox .click();
}
```

The id pattern for text box is like **ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl11_TxtDescrp** & for check box(i guess its checkbox) its like **ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl11_selectchk**

The only changing part is the numeric value **ctl11** & **selectchk/TxtDescrp** so a single loop for range 3-11 along with separate webElement for checkbox & textbox would be required as shown in above code.

I hope the answer helps . . . cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote the folloeing method which replicates your exact question.

```
public static enterVal(int start, int end) {

    for (int i=start; i<=end;i++) {    
        String first = i;
        if (i<10) {
            first = "0"+first;
        }

        String next = i+1;
        if ((i+1)<10) {
            next = "0"+next;
        }
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl"+first+"_TxtDescrp")).sendKeys("eldpone@23");
        if (i==end) {
            break;
        }

        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard_cgConnectionStatistics_ctl"+next+"_selectchk")).click();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of "re-inventing the wheel" in the answers to this question.

The best way to do this is to used the parameterization capability of Junit or TestNG.  I prefer TestNG since the DataProvider is easy to use.  You can create one test method that fills in the field and clicks.   Then, your dataprovider can feed a giant list of arguments into that test method.  What you end up with is a nice report of each individual test with pass/fails for each one.

Here is [a nice example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_parameterized_test.htm).